# error 500 - PromptDialog.Confirm()

Tags: c#, botframework

When i use the code: `PromptDialog.Confirm(context, TrocarEmail,"Seu email atual é: email@email, você gostaria de trocá-lo?");` i get a exception `POST 500 [message] me envie a fatura por email` 
i'm using the Emulator(v3.5.25);

Just for you understand the conversation
user: send me my bill by email
bot: its your email? email@email.com, do you wanna change it? //here is my problem
user: yes/no
...

see the line 61 in [my code](https://github.com/italojs/ChatBotCobranca/blob/start-with-prompts/ChatBotCobranca/Dialogs/DialogHub.cs)

Exception:

```
{
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "invalid need: expected Call, have Poll",
"exceptionType": "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidNeedException",
"stackTrace": " em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IWaiter<C>.NextWait[T]()\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IWaiter.NextWaitT\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Extensions.Wait[C,T](IFiber1 fiber, Rest2 resumeHandler)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IDialogStack.Wait[R](ResumeAfter1 resume)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogContext.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IDialogStack.Wait[R](ResumeAfter1 resume)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Extensions.Wait(IDialogStack stack, ResumeAfter1 resume)\r\n em ChatBotCobranca.Dialogs.DialogHub.<EnviaEmail>d__3.MoveNext() na C:\\Users\\italo\\Documents\\doc\\programação\\ChatBotCobranca\\ChatBotCobranca\\Dialogs\\DialogHub.cs:linha 69\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog1.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()\r\n em ChatBotCobranca.Dialogs.DialogHub.<TrocarEmail>d__4.MoveNext() na C:\\Users\\italo\\Documents\\doc\\programação\\ChatBotCobranca\\ChatBotCobranca\\Dialogs\\DialogHub.cs:linha 75\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume1.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume1.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__211.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.d__51.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LocalizedDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__21.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringDialogTask1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__61.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__61.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__61.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n em ChatBotCobranca.MessagesController.d__0.MoveNext() na C:\Users\italo\Documents\doc\programação\ChatBotCobranca\ChatBotCobranca\Controllers\MessagesController.cs:linha 28\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n em System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
}
Log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the call to the `context.Wait` method to the `else` clause in your `EnviaEmail` method, right after your `PostAsync`.

You cannot perform a Wait after calling a dialog.